# Safari position fixed, flexbox doesn't get positioned well

Tags: css, safari, position, flexbox

So my logo doesn't go to the left properly in Safari browser only, I was wondering what's wrong with it

thanks

Comment: Is it about iOS and/or OS X? Would any of those [2 solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22167383/137626) work for you?

Comment: I checked in on both iOS tablet and OSX in Safari browser, and it's not positioned to the left edge! I wonder what the hell is wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the thing is if you use `flex-direction: column;` in Safari , you have to also mention `flex-wrap: nowrap;` otherwise it will add the width of each flex-item to it's parent container, thanks to Sergey for hinting that.

Answer (score 1):

For the flex container always use prefixes (which you already do).

If you want to align logo to the left, simply add

```
flex-wrap: nowrap;
```

Another good practise with flexboxes for safari is always use flex property.
like so

```
  -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -moz-box-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
```

P.S. This might be an [good article](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/) to start with

Comment: thanks a lot Sergey, nowrap just moved the whole logo thingy to middle but not to the left edge